# Is Jar-Jar Binks responsible for the creation of the Empire?

Tags: star-wars, empire, jar-jar-binks

I have heard some claim that Jar-Jar Binks was responsible for the creation of the Empire. If so, how, and was he the sole reason, or were there other elements?

Comment: I have a feeling this was answered here before, though may have been just a comment thread...

Comment: Short answer is, he happened to have been in some situations that have assisted the creation of the Empire (such as proposing extra powers for Palpatine when acting as a Senator); but wasn't "responsible" in a sense of, if he wasn't there, Palpatine's plans would still have worked, pretty much the same way.

Comment: @DVK Well it didn't show up when I searched, so you're probably right. (I'm new on the scifi stack exchange if you couldn't tell)

Comment: Well, I can't find it at the moment either, so you certainly can't and shouldn't be faulted for lack of effort even if I was remembering correctly and there's already an answer :)

Comment: What is the *Jar-Jar* of which you speak?

Comment: @DVK [Jar-Jar's role as a Senator was mentioned in this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12224/2242)

Comment: @SSumner - specifically [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12809/976)

Comment: One of the most powerful Sith Lord of all time who is cunning, calculating, careful, and long-term thinking is going to have a plan that is contingent on one of the gullible natives from his planet being there to make a proposal to the senate? Um, no.

Comment: @JamesChristopher - Actually, Palpatine was the Apprentice. Jar-Jar was the Master

Comment: yousa mean, like, intentionally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That scene occurred in Episode II where

> Padme had to go back to Naboo so she made him her proxy to the senate.

And then Palpatine

> Social engineered him into putting the motion before the senate (by looking at him and saying words to the effect of "if only there were someone brave enough to make this motion").  The motion was that Palpatine be granted emergency powers, which he used to raise a grand army of the republic aka the clone army aka the stormtroopers.

So he was involved, but if he had not done it then Palpatine would have just tricked or ordered someone else to do it