# Did George Lucas ever comment on why he created Jar Jar Binks?

Tags: star-wars, jar-jar-binks

Everyone seems to hate Jar Jar Binks.  So why did George Lucas create him?  The story of Binks and his people doesn't really contribute anything to the story, and I find that the parts involving Binks and his people are annoying or boring, adding unnecessary length to The Phantom Menace (which is boring enough with all that trade federation stuff and the endless pod racing).

So why exactly did he do it?  What necessary element did Lucas feel that Binks was contributing that Star Wars would have lacked otherwise?

Has he ever said anything directly about Binks?

Comment: Same reason as the Ewoks...

Comment: Never understood the hate against Jar Jar. I believe he was a funny sidekick. And yes, he did contribute to the story.

Comment: I've always seen the whole Gungan story as a tool to show what kind of ruler Padmé is. I think it does a pretty good job at that.

Comment: The Ewoks may be cutesy and annoying, but **they contribute to the plot**, by showing the heroes the back way to the Imperial bunker and then killing a whole lot of stormtroopers. Shameless self-promotion: I've [argued](http://blog.iainroberts.com/2015/07/a-good-feature-of-phantom-menace.html) Padme's alliance with the Gungans is a strong point in Ep1, but [Jar Jar himself](http://blog.iainroberts.com/2015/08/bad-motivator-star-wars-episode-1.html) is almost completely superfluous.

Comment: Because he hates the fans.  Anti-life justifies his hate.

Comment: No one ever accused George Lucas of being a good writer. Remember the screenplays for episodes V and VI were written by Lawrence Kasdan, who is one of the best screenwriters of the 80s. Lucas certainly created the story line and broad strokes of how it would play out, but a good story idea, or more to the point, a good character idea, can be ruined by bad writing.

Comment: Does C-3PO really contribute anything to the story? What about Chewbacca?

Comment: Jar Jar hate always seems to be one of those things that a vocal portion of people like to rant about. I'd guess most people really don't care for him too strongly in one way or another. I don't hate him any more than the quirky C-3PO. Jar Jar is just doofy. Is it unwarranted at times? Sure.

Comment: I can't believe nobody has pointed out the racism issue: http://articles.baltimoresun.com/1999-06-05/news/9906050180_1_jar-jar-binks-phantom

Comment: @zipquincy - **Mindwin** did in comments to **phantom42**'s answer. And let's not forget the accent of the Trade Federation envoys. -- Anyway, this kind of thing happens when directors become too big for their staff to effectively criticize their ideas --> Elf/Dwarf "romance" in The Hobbit anyone **:p**

Comment: @Holger: C-3PO doesn't do much on his own, but functions as a sidekick/translator for R2-D2, who certainly does contribute. And when C-3PO isn't doing anything interesting, the script is ruthless in getting him out of the way: He is dismembered on Bespin, and literally **turned off** in Kenobi's house and when the *Millennium Falcon* hides on the asteroid. (If only Jar-Jar had an off switch, or at least a mute button...) As for Chewbacca, he arguably saves the entire Rebellion when he captures the Imperial AT-AT on Endor, and that's just for starters.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit -- Not to mention that, for the first movie, the story is told largely (entirely?) from **R2** *and* **3PO**'s POV.

Comment: @user23715: Indeed. And now I think of it, the roles are reversed in the Endor sequence of Ep6, with C-3PO achieving much more. The scenes with C-3PO and the Ewoks are (a) funnier than anything Jar-Jar ever did, and (b) advance the plot, as he is instrumental in getting the Ewoks' help. Although Threepio had a point; it **is** somewhat unethical to manipulate a Stone Age people by impersonating one of their gods, especially if you're persuading them to make war on the Galactic Empire...

Comment: @zipquincy the rolling stone article i posted in my answer has a quote from lucas about the accent portion of the racism issue. i didn't mention it in the answer because it's not pertinent to the question as asked.

Comment: @Holger You are certainly right about Chewie as he wasn't even awarded a medal at the end of Ep.4

Comment: @FlorianPeschka you [censored]

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit Jar-Jar made [very important contributions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12809/4698)  as well.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka you silly troll...

Comment: **Obviously,** this movie about trade disputes is for little kids! If there's one thing little kids love, it's senators and their political intrigue. DUH! That reminds me: man, I really don't like George Lucas.

Comment: @MeatTrademark the trade disputes plot is possibly why lucas felt like he *needed* comic relief such as jar jar to begin with - something to help keep the kids attentions.

Comment: @phantom42 But his claim that it's a kids movie seems ridiculous given that subject matter. Trade disputes? I think it's more *pandering* than anything. Trying to please **everyone** and mostly only pleasing the little kids who can't see what a hot mess it is. At least one 6-year-old mentioned below likes it and Jar Jar. Me? I can't watch it without the RiffTrax commentary.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit As Malcolm says, Jar Jar made about as important contributions to the plot as the Ewoks. Moreover, in both cases, it’s not the _existence_ of Jar Jar/the Ewoks that gets people all het up, but their _portrayal_. And that is irrelevant to their contributions. Jar Jar didn’t have to have flappy ears and a funny accent to bring about the Amidala/Gungan alliance, and the Ewoks didn’t have to be freakish, grunty little furballs to help the Heroes find and take down the Imperial bunker. Their functions are separate from their portrayals.

Comment: Because he's a schmuck.

Comment: This question is ***definitely not primarily opinion based!***  I can see how people may have construed that from the title (which I have now edited), but the question is asking about whether Lucas ever said why he created Jar Jar, not why we *think* he created him!

Comment: @N_Soong - Even if that's true, it's also a dupe.

Comment: @WadCheber yes, I agree it's a dupe, but I'm just making the point that it's definitely not 'primarily opinion based' - just really annoys me when people don't bother to read the whole question and judge it by it's title

Answer (score 35):

## For the laughs...

The [Wikipedia page on Jar Jar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jar_Jar_Binks) explains (emphasis mine)

> Star Wars creator George Lucas stated that he feels there is a section
>   of the fanbase who get upset with aspects of Star Wars because "[t]he
>   movies are for children but they don't want to admit that... There is
>   a small group of fans **that do not like comic sidekicks**. They want the
>   films to be tough like The Terminator, and they get very upset and
>   opinionated about anything that has anything to do with being
>   childlike."

The above quote is sourced from [this interview](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/entertainment/394542.stm).  This makes it pretty clear that Lucas had intended Jar Jar, at least partially to be **comic relief**.  This seems to have failed for most of the audience.

## ... and for the kids

So one aspect was definitely as comic relief.  But the other aspect, as Wiki explains, is:

> Rob Coleman, who was the lead on the Industrial Light
>   & Magic animation team, warned Lucas that the team thought Jar Jar's
>   character came across poorly. **Lucas told him that he specifically put
>   Jar Jar in the film to appeal to small children twelve or under**

Comment: an astute answer

Comment: Your second link doesn't go to an interview or have that quote anywhere on the page.

Comment: "Lucas told him that he specifically put Jar Jar in the film to appeal to small children twelve or under" - and it works.  My 6 year old has seen a few of the Star Wars movies, and says Episode 1 is her favorite, specifically because of Jar Jar.

Comment: Kids love politics. That's what I' always sa- wait. THIS MAKES NO SENSE!! *A MOVIE ABOUT TRADE AGREEMENTS IS FOR LITTLE KIDS?!* (Looks at ceiling like an Episode IV Vader:) **NO!!!!!**

Comment: My 6-year-old also loves Jar Jar, but she doesn't go to conventions or post on Internet forums. I think the assumption that he misses for "most of the audience" could be a false impression.

Comment: @brian_o -- No, because virtually all of today's 6-year-olds will become adults and change their minds drastically. Happened to me and *all* my friends and anyone else I've ever asked over the age of 14.

Comment: @Meat The movies are **also** for children. Must any movie that deals with politics automatically eschew all comedy and lightheartedness and only target politically minded adults? Of course not. Politics and war are the two overarching themes in the _Star Wars_ movies, but they’re perfectly watchable by children all the same because they’re specifically geared towards both adults and children. Jar Jar is just one of the elements geared towards children.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Please note I was addressing the answer above, specifically *"George Lucas stated that he feels there is a section of the fanbase who get upset with aspects of Star Wars because "[t]he movies are for children but they don't want to admit that..."* Armed with this knowledge, hopefully my snarky humor makes sense. I wasn't just blathering without cause. (PS- I agree with your comment below the OP. I hate Jar Jar and its portrayal, but it did serve a purpose. (I refer to Jar Jar in a gender-free fashion, like I would any garbage. [adjusts tie] Thank you, I'm outta here!))

Comment: @Meat Yes, I realised that—my point was that Lucas’ words don’t necessarily mean that _Star Wars_ are children’s movies as such. The aspect of the fan base that Lucas is talking about doesn’t want to admit that _Star Wars_ are movies made to be enjoyed by children as well—the ‘also’ in my first comment is, to me, implicit in Lucas’ statement.

Comment: @phantom42 oh doesn't it?  Sorry - my bad!

Answer (score 24):

Lucas believes that all characters exist in the stories to move the plot, Jar Jar included.

Lucas [was quoted as saying](http://www.sfgate.com/entertainment/article/Lucas-strikes-back-Star-Wars-creator-defends-2837554.php)

> "The characters are only there to make the story move forward . . . their personalities revolve around the plot," the soft-spoken mogul explained. "In 'Episode I,' Jar Jar uses his ties to the Jedi to bring together two disparate societies, the Gungans and Naboo. Therefore, he served the plot."

This continues in Episode 2 as Jar Jar inadvertently helps set Palpatine up for his rise to power by moving that the senate grant Palpatine emergency powers.

In [an earlier interview](http://www.rollingstone.com/movies/news/jar-jar-binks-a-digital-star-is-born-19990624), Lucas admitted that Jar Jar also serves as intentional comic relief.

> Lucas doesn't care too terribly much that some folks have a problem with Jar Jar. "**I think the comic-relief character is an important dramatic device,**" he says. "Some of the fans that want The Phantom Menace to be The Terminator don't like the idea that there are comic characters in it. I certainly am not going to make a grim bloodfest out of Star Wars."

Comment: Merchandising..

Comment: The trouble is, Jar-Jar does not in fact establish any ties between the Naboo and Gungans. Padme does that herself, by going into the swamp and talking to the Gungan chief in person. Okay, Jar-Jar tells her how to get there, but the same thing could have been accomplished by an inanimate object like a map. His screen time is vastly disproportionate to his actual effect on the story.

Comment: You'll note that I never said any of this was objectively correct. I specifically prefaced this answer with the words "**Lucas believes**".

Comment: @phantom42: Yes, I appreciate that. My above comment was a criticism of Lucas, not you. :-)

Comment: Wait, Jar Jar was supposed to be comic relief? Guess they should have made him funny, then.

Comment: @ToddWilcox the first time I watched the movie he seemed like a bad ethnical joke (the kind that makes you facepalm till your nose hurts). The impression only got reinforced on every viewing afterwards.

Comment: @Mindwin: For once, I'm glad that an aspect of a film was lost in translation to my native language.

Comment: @Jakob "Moirchandizing!" Obviously, I'm no Mel Brooks.

Comment: Jar-Jar the Prequel!

Answer (score 19):

> So why exactly did he do it?

*Out of canon answer*

---

From a plot perspective, *something* has to drive Anakin to the dark side. Why use character development when you can have <s>no character development and stupid characters</s> Jar Jar?

Having a Jar Jar like influence around someone's youth traumatized Anakin. Jar Jar was around for a large amount of his formative years and a constant irritant. He worked closely with Anakin and Palpatine during his youth and childhood while Palpatine gained influence with Amidala. This influence eventually is enough that when the moment was right, Jar Jar could suggest the following <s>plot device</s>:

> It's a clear desa Separatists made a pact witha desa Federation du Trade. Senators! Dellow felegates! In response to this direct threat to the Republic, mesa propose that the Senate give immediately emergency powers to the Supreme Chancellor!

From a plot perspective, a character such as Jar Jar was needed - no one would believe anyone else could suggest such things. A stupid, easily manipulated senator was required. This is why Palpatine had been building a relationship to manipulate him and ultimately control him. The secondary purpose is that by keeping Jar Jar around Anakin for his childhood, he is wearing Anakin down, making him more vulnerable to the eventual turn to the dark side. Being forced to be around Jar Jar makes Anakin angry and during his Jedi training, burying these feelings results in a deep well of anger Palpatine is filling for years.

Anakin is forced to turn to Amidala in light of the trauma he is forced to go through during his childhood due to Jar Jar. This is necessary in order to make Anakin's terrible relational dialog <s>make any sense at all</s> only slightly less bad. These repressed memories drive him seek relational comfort and consolation from Amidala, because she too has experienced the horrible effect of Jar Jar. The <s>absolutely awful dialog</s> conversations they have are a result of his repressed childhood memories, her interactions with Jar Jar, and his attempts to cope with these memories.

This repression is ultimately fulfilled when Vader allows Tarkin to blow up an [entire planet](https://youtu.be/qBAZGtBfcY4?t=1m15s) just to get rid of Jar Jar.

Comment: hehehehehehehehe

Comment: No, this is definitely canon.

Comment: **:D** *<tears>*

Comment: This isn't really a place for joke answers, but damn my eyes. I upvoted against all reason. I hates me some Jar Jar.

Comment: I joined just so I could upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Compare Jar Jar Binks to C-3PO.

Both characters are extremely similar to each other conceptually and play a similar role in their respective story.

Both are mostly useless in general, but are situationally useful enough to take along.  (C-3PO can talk to anything and Jar Jar can guild the Jedi to the Gungan people.)

Both are rather "goofy", but C-3PO is a gold-plated droid (cool!), and Jar Jar is a floppy eared something or other (eh).